# SeleniumBase multithread is not working, I am using UC with it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, reddit, seleniumbase

I am trying to login to reddit using SeleniumBase, I am a top moderator trying to add a bot to my community which can automate tasks for me to keep the community clean, for some reason when i open the browser using SeleniumBase UC it will not allow me to login using this code

```
import pytest
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__, "--uc", "-n2", "-s")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("", [[]] * 2)
def test_multi_threaded(sb):
    sb.open("https://www.reddit.com/login/")
    try:
        sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=5.25)
        sb.post_message("Selenium wasn't detected!", duration=2.8)
        sb._print("\n Success! Website did not detect Selenium! ")
    except Exception:
        sb.fail('Selenium was detected! Try using: "pytest --uc"')
```

As soon as the browser go to reddit login page i login manually and there it does not let me in for some reason, I tried to login using my normal browser and it worked, but using the SeleniumBase broswer it keep saying the account is incorrect

Comment: It may be because of an anti-bot system. Can you try to remove the "--uc" flag ?

Comment: uc is working fine i checked it on fingerprint.com and other website it is undetectable, i think its coming from seleniumbase ? this is really werid

Comment: The `"OH YEAH, you passed!"` is only for https://nowsecure.nl/#relax
Looks like you took the example from https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/presenter/multi_uc.py and then swapped the URL without updating the rest of the test.